# List items on Navigation bar move forward when I hover the mouse on it

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me in this problem please. When I bring the mouse over TOYOTA,  the HONDA and CONTACT US move forward. I don't want this. I just want that when I bring mouse over TOYOTA and HONDA the next list iten should not move forward.  How to fix it. 
Here is my code.

```css
body {background-color: black;}
 ul {list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
ul li {float: left;
      
   }
li ul {display: none;}

ul li a {display:block;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding:30px 60px;
 
         color: lightgray;
}

ul li a:hover {background: white;
               color: red;
           
}
 li:hover ul {
    display:block;
     }
    li:hover li{ 
    float: none;
    background: red;      
  }
```

```html
<body>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">TOYOTA</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">TOYOTA COROLLA PRIUS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">TOYOTA COROLLA ALTIS</a></li>  
  </ul>
  </li> 
 <li><a href="#">HONDA</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">HONDA</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">HONDA</a></li>  
  </ul>
  
  </li> 
 <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li> 
 </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just apply

```
li:hover ul{
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: The answer proved to be really helpful...the problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of your `ul li` elements to a fixed value.
Otherwise the width of your 'TOYOTA' element will change, hence moving the element next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
body > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #000;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #CCC;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #F00;

}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

li:hover li {
  background-color: #F00;         
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  body > ul {
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 50%;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: left;
  }

  body > ul > li {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

avoid using float and position properties if there is another solution. I suggest you to display your items vertically on small devices because they're tight. Also, use hex notation rather colors name

Comment: using the above code all the elements float to left, but what if I want all the element to float to right.

Comment: for all devices or only for desktop ?

Comment: For all devices